# JSON загружает лишние неизвестные символы

Tags: json, парсер, java, android, mysql

JSON парсер возвращает `ï»¿ï»¿{"success":1,"data":[{"dateTime":"2015-03-02 19:43:04","t_inside":"23.5","t_outside":"0.29","Pressure":"755.7","Humidity":"34.6"}]}`, хотя  `ï»¿ï»¿`, естественно, не запланировано. В браузере все выводит нормально. Кодировку менял. В ином случае выводит? Подскажите, в чем может быть дело.

Код парсера (самый обыкновенный):

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method, List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if (method == "POST") {
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } else if (method == "GET") {
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
       // json = json.substring(6);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;
}}
```

И код PHP'ешника:

```
<?php $db_table = 'HomeWeatherStation'; $response = array(); include("conec.php");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM " . $db_table . " ORDER BY dateTime desc LIMIT 1");

if (!empty($result)) {
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

        $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $data = array();
        $data["dateTime"] = $result["dateTime"];
        $data["t_inside"] = $result["t_inside"];
        $data["t_outside"] = $result["t_outside"];
        $data["Pressure"] = $result["Pressure"];
        $data["Humidity"] = $result["Humidity"];
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["data"] = array();

        array_push($response["data"], $data);

        echo json_encode($response);
    } 
    else {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No 1 found";

        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} 
else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No 2 found";

    echo json_encode($response);
} ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

utf-bom, utf-bom

это всё наш дружелюбный utf-bom!

Вам нужно пересохранить файлы проекта в кодировке UTF-8 без BOM (судя по всему, у вас два не очень хороших файла). Это можно сделать в Notepad++ или PHPStorm.

А вообще я бы бэкенд делал тоже на яве в таком случае.

Comment: @Dumpling, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).